# Kendo Grid - Column/Link Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working with Kendo UI's grid in a C# asp.NET application.

I have a grid being populated from a model(see code below).

In my grid I return 3 columns, but I only want to show 2. I want to return the FileName as the text in the StreamId column's link.  Currently I have to hard code "View Document" as the link text, but I want to just create link text based on the file name.

My Grid look's like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AnimalDocumentViewModel>()
                      .Name("AttachmentListGrid")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "grid attachmentList"})
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound ( c => c.StreamId ).ClientTemplate ( "<a class='active' href='" + Url.Action ( "DownloadAttachment" , "Animal" ) + "?id=#= StreamId #'>"+"View Document"+"</a>" ).Title ( "" );
                          columns.Bound(c => c.FileName).Title(Resources.FileName);
                          columns.Bound(c => c.DocumentType).Title(Resources.Type);
                      })
                      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                          .Ajax()
                          .Read(read => read.Action("GetAnimalDocumentsGridResult", "Animal", new {Model.AnimalId}))
                      //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handlerLogEventsList"))
                      )
                      .Navigatable()
                      .Sortable()
                      .AutoBind(true)
       )
```

I am currently using Jquery to solve this, but I do not like doing it this way:

```
<script>
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
        $("#AttachmentListGrid table tr td:nth-child(2), #AttachmentListGrid table tr th:nth-child(2)").hide();
             $("#AttachmentListGrid table tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
                 var a = $(this).text();
                 console.log(a);
                 $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(1)  a").text(a);
             });



        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user below code..

```
.ClientTemplate("<a title=\"#=FileName#\">#=FileName#</a>")
```

I hope this might be help you..